# Bootstrap Switch doesn't render properly at the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-switch

When user is visiting my webpage, bootstrap switch doesn't render properly at the first time, look:

[image]

Then, other times normal:

[image]

What I think is happening is that the page is rendering first than the Bootstrap Switch! Even using the Jquery ready function, as below:

```
$(function() {

    var btn_is_active = $("#btn-is-active");
    var btn_is_public = $("#btn-is-public");

    btn_is_active.bootstrapSwitch('state', {{ event.is_active|lower }});
    btn_is_public.bootstrapSwitch('state', {{ event.is_public|lower }});
});
```

I really want to avoid this kind of bad experience for the user, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Can you give us a link towards your page or maybe an SSCE snippet ?

Comment: Sure! http://191.252.59.101/dashboard/manage_event/ ... user ph@guia.com , pass: 123  Just copy and paste any Facebook Public Event into field and click on "Confirmar", you will see!